# Share code between view specs

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have several view specs: edit, index, new, show, for a given Rails (3) controller and I'd like to have some of the boilerplate setup code shared between them.  I'd like to avoid placing it in the spec_helper.rb file.   Any ideas?

To be more specific, in spec/views/steps, I have four files: {edit,new,show,index}.html.erb_spec.rb.  I would like for them to share some code, such as

```
  let(:workflow) do
    document = Factory.create(:document)
    document.user = user
    document.save!
    document.workflow
  end
```

For example - the exact code does not matter.  I would like to do this without putting it in spec_helper.rb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find that rspec has exactly the thing for this: [shared context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context).

It will allow you to do something like this

```
shared_context 'workflow' do
  let(:workflow) do
    document = Factory.create(:document)
    document.user = user
    document.save!
    document.workflow
  end
end
```

If you need to share this between different spec-files, write this in a file that you store inside `spec/support`. In your test you can then write:

```
describe 'Something' do
  include_context 'workflow'

  it 'behaves correctly' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: notice that `spec/support` folder is just a convention and Rspec won't autorequire files from it, so you'll need to `require 'spec/support/filey'`

Comment: True. I usually include the following line in my `rails_helper.rb` (used to be spec_helper) : `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a `shared context`: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context